# After enabling the "experimentalInteractiveRunEvents" flag to run the after:spec event in Cypress IDE : after:spec event is not calling

Tags: cypress, config, testrail, interactive-mode

I have enabled the "experimentalInteractiveRunEvents": true in cypress.json to run the after:spec event of cypress-testRail-simple plugin through cypress IDE.

link for plugin : https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-testrail-simple.git

I am using this event in cypress-testRail-simple's plugin.js file.

[image]

I have defined plugin in plugins -> index.js
[image]

enabled the flag in cypress.json file:

[image]

I have multiple spec files.

**When running through command line :**
npx cypress run

after:spec - getting called after all the spec run finish.

**When running through cypress IDE :**
npx cypress open

after:spec - called zero time

reference : [how to run the cypress in interactive mode with flag enabled](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/////////restart-server/)

Comment: Please add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: Added Please check!

Answer (score 0):

There's a  fundamental difference between `npx cypress open` (interactive mode) and `npx cypress run` (command line mode).

**Interactive mode**

All the specs are run as in a single continuous run, as if they had been written as ***one spec***. Because of this, `before:spec` is called only one.

**Command line mode**

All specs are run as separate runs, hence two calls to `before:spec`.

---

From [After Spec API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-spec-api#Syntax)

> When running cypress via cypress open, the event will fire **when the browser closes.**

Comment: I am using cypress-testrail-simple plugin which is using after:spec event that is the mandatory!

Comment: Yeah, that's also the case with Mochawesome reporter plugin.